# Problems with Go, GopherJS and vecty versions

Tags: go, webassembly, gopherjs

There's three language ([Go](https://golang.org/)), compiler ([GopherJS](https://github.com/gopherjs/gopherjs)) and library ([Vecty](https://github.com/hexops/vecty)).
The problem is that GopherJS requires Go in version 12.x and Vecty requires Go in version 1.14+.
Somebody know how to set everytihng to build Vecty project with GopherJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** April 6, 2021 [GopherJS 1.16 was released](https://medium.com/gopherjs/gopherjs-1-16-released-73805c81674c), which may allow you to use modern versions of this library.

---

<strike>GopherJS has been [effectively abandoned](https://github.com/gopherjs/gopherjs/issues/894), and will not be adding support for Go 1.13 or later.</strike> That said, there [has been some work](https://github.com/gopherjs/gopherjs/pull/964) to support Go 1.13 and 1.14 in some forks. It remains to be seen how much traction a fork is likely to gain moving forward.

You may have some success using one of the unofficial forks, if you really need this to work.

So in summary, your options are:

1. Use an unofficial fork of GopherJS which supports Go 1.14 sufficiently for your needs.
2. Use an old or backported* version of Vecty which works with Go 1.12 and GopherJS
3. Consider using Go/WASM in place of GopherJS.

---

*You'll likely have to do this backport yourself.